# new vs initialize in Ruby

Tags: ruby

When we create a new instance of a class, we do the following:

Given the class:

```
class Person
  def initialize
  end
end

person = Person.new
```

I believe that since `class Person` is an instance of `Class`, the `new` method is defined there. However, how is the initialize method called?

Comment: @rsenna it's not a direct dup.

Comment: Hey there Hommer Smith,

It seems that the answer to your question is really that calling Person.new *is* what calls the initialize method. With the case of the initialize method it is that the Ruby language simply expects and seeks out a method named initialize which it then runs any time the you create a new instance of a class.

Here's the first write up I found:
http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/objinitialization.html